# Repaint won't work in custom panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, repaint

I have a problem with repainting my Panel. My idea for a animation was to fill an Array with int[]'s. That's the part that works. now to animate it I take the Array and fill a variable int[] with the int[] from the array. Then I call repaint to repaint the image with all the numbers. but it doesn't repaint until the last repaint. any one who has an idea?
the two classes where I think the problem lies. are given below (the code might be chaotic).

What my idea is, is that I want to press the button shellSort. whan I have pressed this button the code will go through a for loop filling a array in the pannel with integers. then it should repaint my panel which it does not do.

Edited: I think my problem is that it never leaves the for loop until it's finished. how do i stop a for loop to repaint my Panel? and then continue where i left off?

i reconstructed my problem in a small example
code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Repainten {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI g = new GUI();
    }
}


public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JButton button;
    private Panel p;
    private int[] henk = {10, 6, 4, 2, 3, 7, 9};

    public GUI() {
        this.setTitle("getallen");
        this.setSize(200, 200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        button = new JButton("Button");
        p = new Panel();
        button.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.add(button);
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.add(p);
        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //add(button);
        add(p);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button) {
            animeer();
        }
    }
    public void animeer() {
        for (final int a : henk) {                     
            p.cijfer = a;
            p.repaint();
        }
    }
}
public class Panel extends JPanel{
    public int cijfer = 0;

    public Panel(){

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Font font = new Font("Algerian", Font.PLAIN, 100);
        g.setFont(font);
        System.out.println(cijfer);
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(cijfer), 60,110);

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes it is a bit chaotic. Please put up a runnable example (with main). Noone is going to look at what you just posted up. Remove any code that is not part of the problem, eg. do we need any of that image code?

Comment: and put all the code in one block, so people can quickly copy and paste the code into their IDEs and give you an answer quickly. The less work you get us to do, the more likely you will get an answer

Comment: I hope this is better :)

Comment: Apart from the fact that those links dont work, no one wants to download code from another location. please post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Remove the read and write methods. We cannot run your example with these read and write methods! Create a mock method that returns values, instead.

Comment: this does not work. You have a compile error : shellSort not initialisating

Comment: I removed lots of code now with the reading and writing. but I don;t realy know how to make a mock method. I don;t get a compile error :/ think u miss some code then :/

Comment: I have a question because i think my problem is that it never leaves the for loop until it's finished. how do i stop a for loop to repaint my Panel? and then continue where i left off?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `repaint` is optimized so that multiple calls to the method in quick succession will result in only the last call being made. The solution is to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

```
Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {

      int index = 0;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      p.cijfer = henk[index];
      index++;
      p.repaint();

      if (index == henk.length) {
         Timer timer = (Timer) e.getSource();
         timer.stop();
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Component won't always repaint immediately...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29